# mysql time comparison

Tags: mysql

I have job_start and job_end times and timediff will give me the time difference. Now I want to see if that job took more than 2 hrs 30 min. How do I compare it? I am getting errora if I do it like this:

```
timediff(job_start,job_end)> '2:30:00'    
timediff(job_start,job_end)> time(2:30:00)   
timediff(job_start,job_end)> time_format(2:30:00)
```

Nothing of the above syntax is working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From mysql docs for function [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

The unit for the result (an integer) is given by the unit argument. 
The legal values for unit are the same as those listed in the description of the TIMESTAMPADD() function.

Which should be one of the following values: MICROSECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.

Result if integer.I recommend MINUTE:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, job_start, job_end) > 150
```

(2 * 60 + 30) mins = 150 mins  = 2,5 hours

Comment: Don't you mean `TIMESTAMPDIFF` rather than `TIMEDIFF`?