# How to make a select and compare TIME at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

i want to select all from organisor but only if $end_t is equal or less  to "end_time" a row in the table

i have stored $end_t as String in the database 
can i have an response how to do this :)

it is a matching for talking a ride

```
<?php

    $date_t='3-19-2014';    
    $departure_t='10:21 PM';
    $end_t='10:30 PM';
    $deparure_a='as';
    $destination_a='asa';

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "xxxxxxxxxx");

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM organisor WHERE date_trip='$date_t'and 
            departure_time='$departure_t'and departure_address='$deparure_a' and    destination_address='$destination_a'");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          echo $row['O_id'] . " " . $row['username']. " " . $row['date_trip']. " " .   $row['departure_time'];
          echo "<br>";
      }
?>
```

Comment: First off, never post passwords on a sit like this. Secondly, you should be storing the time as a time, not a string. You will find it damn hard to compare strings logically like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql time comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983699/mysql-time-comparison)

Comment: @Fluffeh infact i am testing a php page but the data stored in my database is done my an android application i do have a dialog box that ask me to select time ,do u have a solution for that ?

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983699/mysql-time-comparison

Comment: @AndreschSerj thank's 

i have found the solution 

SELECT * FROM organisor WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_trip,'%m-%d-%Y')=STR_TO_DATE('$date_t','%m-%d-%Y') and STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%l:%i %p')<=STR_TO_DATE('$departure_t','%l:%i %p')

part of the query

Comment: Congrats. Make sure to post your own solution as an aswer and come back a few days later to accept it. This way, when people come here in the future they will directly see the solution. Also, bored people sorting thru unanswered questions won't come here telling you what you already know :D